# change the theme of the activities from dark to white

Tags: android, themes

from an unclear reason the theme of all my activities was change to a dark one. I try to return it to the deafult theme by changing the code in the Manifest.xml, but without success.

this is the code of Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myhalf">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Background" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".controller.testingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".controller.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".controller.LookingFor" />
        <activity android:name=".controller.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".controller.MatchMakerRegistering" />
        <activity android:name=".controller.EditProfile"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the one of the activities that still stay dark:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`android:theme="@style/Background"` ovveride `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` for your activity. BTW your theme look pretty same like `@android:style/DeviceDefault`.

Check on layout.xml if u not overide themes for views. Check styles.xml folder may be u ovveride colors. Or delete one of them. You can create new style in styles.xml and inherit any default style with your attributtes.